# PVCS Promotion Group

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, pvcs

Currently I am migrating `PVCS` source code to `GIT` Repository.

As there is no specific tool which will migrate `PVCS` to `GIT`. I used [3rd party tool](https://www.polarion.com/) and SVN as bridge repository.

I am successful in migrating PVCS code to `SVN` as mentioned below.

```
PVCS Trunk --> SVN Trunk
PVCS branches -->  SVN Branches
PVCS Labels --> SVN Tags
```

After the migration I found that one more step was missing.

In `PVCS` we have a Promotion Group and it is not migrated to `SVN`.

Kindly let me know what is Promotion Group in `PVCS` and how it will be migrated to `SVN`.

Is there any concept called promotion Group in `Bitbucket`

Comment: You have to explain what a Promotion Group is, because there's no native comparison with SVN or Git as far as I know.

Comment: @AlBlue Thank you for comment. 

Here they have created DEV, Production, QA , Staging. (Promotion groups).

Comment: Still doesn't mean anyone knows what you mean by (Promotion groups).

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to handle this?  I am considering the same course of action, as PVCS support has essentially stopped, and support for Eclipse plugins is 2 years behind

Answer (score 0):

PVCS promotion groups are used to handle the movement of code from dev through qa to production. you define the groups you want.

to do something similar in git you can use branches to represent these different states or "promotion groups". Here is an example [model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).
Take a look at [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to see one way of doing this.